# MS Teams workflow, run only users don't see my flow

Tags: workflow

I have Power Automation flow that use Teams trigger: For selected Message. I can see and use that flow in Teams, by clicking 3 dots: More Options. I add user in Run only users option, but they cannot see flow. I even add user to Co-owner, still no luck.
How can I fix that?

Thanks